# How would I reference a dynamically created jQuery dialog box so I can close it programatically?

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

When I began using jQuery a little over a year ago, I needed to load remote content into a pop-up dialog box. After scouring the internet and trying out several suggested methods for doing this, I came upon a function that worked exactly as I needed it to. However, one problem I've never solved is how to reference the dynamic dialog box so it can be closed from an outside function.

Here's the function that creates the dialog box, appends it to the body, and then loads a page into it:

```
function openDynamicDialog() {
  var url = 'mypage.cfm';
  var dialog = $('`<div style="display:hidden"></div>`').appendTo('body');
    $(dialog).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      title: 'My Title',
      resizable: true,
      modal: true,
      width: 250,
      height: 100,
      close: function(ev, ui) {
             $(this).remove(); // ensures any form variables are reset.
           }, 
      buttons: {
        "Close": function(){ 
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
  });
  // load remote content
  dialog.load(
    url,
    {},
    function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
      dialog.dialog();
     }
  );
  //prevent the browser from following the link
  return false; };
```

I've considered giving that hidden div a hard-coded id value, but I'm not sure if there are drawbacks to that approach.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: why is there a `return false` at the end? what link?

Comment: The 'return false' at the end prevents the browser from opening var url ('mypage.cfm') in a new tab or window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a hard-coded id value for the `<div>` element.

Comment: I'll give it try and let you know how things pan out. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I'm going to give that a try. Thanks for your answer, Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Well im not sure what the `return false` is at the end. so if you don't need that, do this:

```
function openDynamicDialog() {
    var url = 'mypage.cfm';
    var dialog = $('<div>').css('display','none').appendTo('body');
    $(dialog).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        title: 'My Title',
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        width: 250,
        height: 100,
        close: function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).remove(); // ensures any form variables are reset.
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    // load remote content
    dialog.load(
    url, {}, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        dialog.dialog();
    });

    return dialog;
}

//call it like this:
var dialog = openDynamicDialog();
//..code
//close it:
dialog.dialog('close');
```

**OR**

if you still need that `return false`, you can do this on the `var dialog` line of the function:

```
var dialog = $('<div>', {id: 'dialog_id'}).css('display','none').appendTo('body');
```

and then reference it from the outside:

```
var dialog = $('#dialog_id');
```

Comment: he needs return false to prevent the anchor from executing it's default behavior(loading a different page), but in this context it looks unneeded

Comment: @stanislav i see no anchor tag lol, but i did give the OP an option without removing the `return false`

Comment: there's a possibility that he's got something like $('a.clickme').click(openDynamicDialog); somewhere

Comment: @stanislav, its always possible. also don't assume the OP is a `he` the OP is `OP` ^_^

Answer (score 0):

No there shouldn't be any drawback giving it an ID. If you fear of some kind of conflicts then you can give it a class instead, or save a reference to the div object in a global variable.

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav. I'm going to assign an ID to the div and see what happens.